# Can I search by range in Google Maps (or in another map service)?

Tags: google-maps

I'm interested in determining an area that is reachable with maximum (e.g.) 30 minutes by car from a given point. This is not a circle with a given radius. Can I do this search in Google Maps or in another map service somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can't search by a distance, all you can do in Google maps is "Search Nearby".

Follow these instructions to do this:

1. Open the new Google Maps.
2. Search for a location. For example: your work address.
3. Click the search box once.
4. Click Search nearby.
5. Type the category of places you want to search. For example: "coffee shops."
6. Hit Enter.

[*Source*](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/GqGuGPY9Xfc%5B1-25%5D)